# Import missing module

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

What is the convention for properly importing a module in Airflow? 
I would like to import this operator:

`https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/mlengine_operator.py`

using this line:

```
from airflow.contrib.operators import MLEngineTrainingOperator
```

I get the following error: `

> cannot import name MLEngineTrainingOperator

`

Comment: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integration.html#cloud-ml-engine ...the name-space might be `airflow.contrib.operators.mlengine_operator`

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue.

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.mlengine_operator import MLEngineTrainingOperator
```